# Бесплатный хостинг для Laravel проекта

Tags: laravel, hosting, free

Не все хостинги рассчитаны на такой массивный фрэймворк как Ларавел.

У меня был не очень  хороший опыт размещения небольшого проэкта на такой хостинг.

какими вы пользуетесь?  И есть ли бесплатные, которые рассчитаны на Ларавел?

Comment: если настолько все плохо с деньгами, не проще развернуть на своем компе как на сервере?

Comment: хорошо. О каких суммах идёт речь? есть пример?

Comment: у себя - бесплатно, если на каком нибудь сервере нормальном, от 5 баксов

Comment: вот пример https://m.do.co/c/029786bd47ea

Comment: там же нет хостинга.

Comment: как это нету? есть конечно

Comment: Вполне можете использовать облако Амазона с консольным доступом забесплатно (микро конфигурация). Это с учетом того что доменное имя вам не нужно (пока), за которое в любом случае придётся платить отдельно от хостинга.